# How to bind innergrid in datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Basically I am new databinding here i tried to insert the inner grid in each row for displaying marks. Can any one help me how to achieve this one.

XAML Code:

```
   <Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">  
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding marks}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate> 
    </DataGrid>  
</Grid>
```

Below is the code which contains 2 classes one is for Students and another is for marks

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGrid.ItemsSource = GetStudentsInfo();
    }

    private List<Student> GetStudentsInfo()
    {
        List<Student> stdColl = new List<Student>();

        stdColl.Add(new Student() { ID = 1, Name = "AAA", marks = new Marks() { Sub1 = 75, Sub2 = 80, Sub3 = 90 } });
        stdColl.Add(new Student() { ID = 2, Name = "BBB", marks = new Marks() { Sub1 = 45, Sub2 = 50, Sub3 = 70 } });
        stdColl.Add(new Student() { ID = 3, Name = "CCC", marks = new Marks() { Sub1 = 35, Sub2 = 80, Sub3 = 60 } });
        stdColl.Add(new Student() { ID = 4, Name = "DDD", marks = new Marks() { Sub1 = 75, Sub2 = 40, Sub3 = 90 } });

        return stdColl;
    }
}
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Marks marks { get; set; }
}

public class Marks
{
    public int Sub1 { get; set; }
    public int Sub2 { get; set; }
    public int Sub3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner datagrid has to bind to a list just like your outer one.

Make changes to your Mark class

```
public class Mark {

    public int Sub { get; set; }  

}
```

Change the `Mark` property to a list

```
public Marks marks { get; set; }
```

to

```
public List<Mark> Marks { get; set; }
```

When you add a student, give them a new `List` instead of `Mark`

```
stdColl.Add(new Student() { ID = 4, Name = "DDD", Marks = new List<Mark>() { new Mark(){ Sub = 90; } } });
```

Then a minor name change to your binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Marks}"
```

So now your binding looks for property `Marks` inside class `Student`

As another recommendation, look into the MVVM pattern and how to use it.

Comment: Why the error shows - 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GridViewDemo2.Mark>' does not contain a definition for 'Sub'

Comment: @YUG Fixed. Change to `new List<Mark>() { new Mark(){ Sub = 90; } } });`